# How to use a value from one jLabel to another

Tags: java, jlabel, do-while

Is it possible to use a value from one jLabel, to calculate a new value, placed in another jLabel? I am making an airplane booking platform, and have made certain calculations in one jLabel regarding the ticket price. I want to use that in order to do the following:

```
 do{


       jLabel25.get();


   } while(jRadioButton5.isSelected());
```

So basically I want to use a do while loop in order to find the discount, but how can I include all the possible values inside the jLabel? (so I don't have to repeat the calculations).

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail.  JLabels do not calculate anything.  Describe the information you already have available, the results you desire, and the results you’re currently getting.

Comment: @VGR I included more details above^

Comment: You will have to repeat the calculations every time the price or discount factors change.  That cannot be avoided.

Comment: @VGR I mean, to make a do-while loop that goes through the prices (of the already made calculations) and when it is more than 300 euros, then it would be 25% off

Comment: You cannot use a loop unless you put the JLabels into an array or [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

Comment: Your question as well as requirements seems unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for but I'll try my best to help anyway.

Say you have two labels:

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel l("Hello!");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel l("Hello world!");
```

If you now want to set the contents of label1 ("Hello") into label2 ("Hello world!") you can do  the following:

```
label2.setText(label1.getText());
```

Since you used the word calculate in the description of your problem i assume your labels contain numbers that you want to do calculations on.

You could for instance accomplish that with combining the label method .getText() with Integer.parseInt(String s) or Double.parseInt(String s) depending on what type of value you have. So for instance:

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel l("5");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel l("");

int i = Integer.parseInt(label1.getText()); // takes the string from label1 and transforms it to an integer using the parseInt() method.
// i now has the value 5

i = i*5; // an example of some calculation you mentioned you wanted to do

label2.setText(i +""); // transforms the integer value to string and sets it into label2
```

I don't know if i understood your problem correctly, so please elaborate if you need additional help :).